# Urlmanager and Controller::createUrl bug in YII

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I have next rules for urlmanager rules in my  config.main :

```
'<view:(history|our_contacts)>'=>'site/page',
```

Then, in code I use:

```
<?=  CController::createAbsoluteUrl('/site/page', array('view'=>'our_contacts'))  //generate site.ru/our_contacts ?>
```

and

```
<?=  CController::createAbsoluteUrl('/site/page', array('view'=>'test'))  //generate site.ru/test ?>
```

Then, generated:
site.ru/our_contacts - work
site.ru/test - not work

How I set rules for my config, where Controller::createUrl generate next links:

```
site.ru/our_contacts
site.ru/site/page?view=test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right rules:

```
'<view:(agreement|vendors|partners|help|about|howtobuy)>'=> array('site/page' , 'matchValue'=>true),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is:

```
'<view:(history|our_contacts)>'=>'site/page',
```

You code params: `array('view'=>'test')` not validate.

Сan take use only param: `(history|our_contacts)`